# Google Script app.createServerHandler Missing ; before statement line 8

Tags: scripting, syntax-error, google-sites

I'm working on a Leave Request form on our Google site. If I comment out the app.createServerHandler line it is fine. What am I missing from the below code?

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('OIT Leave Request');

//Create a panel to hold the form elements
var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('panel');

//Create event handlers for form
var AllDayBoxHandler() = app.createServerHandler('AllDayBoxEvent');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/ui-service#ServerHandlers).

I believe what you're trying to do is depreciated. But either way I think your setting the handler wrong. Something like:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('OIT Leave Request');

  //Create a panel to hold the form elements
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('panel');

  app.add(panel);

  //Create event handlers for form
  var AllDayBoxHandler = app.createServerHandler('AllDayBoxEvent');

  //Not exactly sure what events a panel can get
  //A button would have a .addClickHandler method
  panel.addOpenHandler(AllDayBoxHandler);
  return app;
}

//The event handler method
function AllDayBoxEvent(e) {
  // your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you very. It seems that most of the functions have been deprecated. I was trying to add the handler for an All Day checkbox. It would grey out the Start / End time fields and put in the full shift. I have some other elements, like 2 dateboxes, that define the form to put in the panel. This is my first time trying to code on a Google Site, and I'm starting to wish it was Sharepoint :(

Comment: It's a bit difficult at first. What I ended up doing was using the recommended way of HTML Service. The tutorial is pretty easy to follow. I only had one issue when working with apps script directly on a Google Site, and that was working with getting data from an external SQL server. However if I were to build, deploy, and embed the same code into a web app using the script editor, it worked just fine (really odd). This unfortunately would prevent you from getting any active session data from the website (such as logged in user). If not using an SQL Server, you'd have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thank you very much! I never imagined that trying to do such a simple form as a leave request would be so difficult on a Google site. I so want my Outlook / Exchange back, but at least I'll get my programming skills a bit of an update. I haven't programmed real-world stuff now for about 9 years.